# Creating dynamic parameter stored procedure

Tags: sql, firebird, procedures

Is it possible to create a dynamic value that can hold any data type value in stored procedures in firebird? Something like:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE something(variable_a dynamic)
RETURNS (status int)
 AS
BEGIN
-- ....
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

Thank you.

Comment: Firebird has no "variant" data type. You may use  `VARCHAR` and `CAST` to do "pseudo variant " type.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in Firebird. The exact data type must be known at procedure compile time.